# How to convert Avro Generic Record to bytes?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

Hi I am working on confluent kafka using .net. I have one consumer which returns generic record. I want to de-serialize the data returned from the consumer.

Below is my consumer implementation.

```
public ConsumeResult<string, GenericRecord> Consume(string topic)
    {
      CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
      ConsumeResult<string, GenericRecord> result;
      while (true)
      {
        try
        {
          result = consumer.Consume(cts.Token);
          return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          this.logger.Error("KafkaClient", $"Error sending message '{e.Message}'");
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
```

I found below link to de-serialize the data returned from the consumer client.

> https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes/GenericDeserializerImpl.cs

In the above link, we have one method Deserialize which accepts topic name and bytes data. I am not sure how to pass my consumerresult type to the dserialize method. Can someone help me in this regard? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `GenericRecord` already is *deserialized*... Not sure I understand why you need to *serialize* back into bytes

Comment: Then how can I de-serialize into c# model?

Comment: You need to use the SpecificRecord consumer instead, using avrogen to create it - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/README.md#working-with-apache-avro

Comment: Thanks. Cant we do it withh GenericRecord? because my requirement is to work with GenericRecord?

Comment: Sure. Pull out each individual field of GenericRecord into your own class... Make a constructor of your own class that accepts a GenericRecord, for example